# Stuck trying to implement touch and hold (bullet firing)? - cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I've been having a lot of trouble implementing a smooth and reliable touch-and-hold solution for firing bullet (sprites) - even after looking at other people's solutions.

The solution has to switch between touch-began, touch moved and touch ended seamlessly: always firing bullets at the touch location until the finger is released. At the moment I have many problems with reliability and stability with every case but touchmoved, which works fine.

The exact issue is around half the time a finger is held down (touchBegan + scheduler) the bullets appear but disappear a second later but other times they move towards the touch perfectly - something is deleting them and i don't have much experience with schedulers or actions to know what.

Heres my code, I've used 2 different firing methods: one scheduled to run every 0.05 seconds after touchBegan, and one triggered every time touchMoved is detected. The touchMoved one works fine, but getting it to work with the unreliable touchBegan one is trouble. The really annoying part is even if I remove the touch part and just schedule sprites to appear and run scheduled actions non-stop from init, the same reliability problem happens (disappearing/deletion). Maybe I dont understand getting schedulers and actions to play nice, or maybe theres a better touch and hold method? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{ 
... miscellaneous sprite creation
this->schedule(schedule_selector(HelloWorld::fireBullets), 0.05);   
}

void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( pTouches->anyObject() );               // get single-touch as opposed to multitouch

    touchLocation = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(touch->getLocationInView());

    if (touchLocation.x > 400)
    {
        float dX = touchLocation.x - gun->getPosition().x;
        float dY = touchLocation.y - gun->getPosition().y;

        touchAngle = atan2(dY, dX);  
        gun->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(touchAngle));

        cursor->setPosition(touchLocation);

        screenHeld = true;
    }
}

void HelloWorld::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet *pTouches, CCEvent *pEvent)
{
    CCTouch* touch = (CCTouch*)( pTouches->anyObject() );               // for single-touch as opposed to multitouch

    touchLocation = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->convertToGL(touch->getLocationInView());

    if (touchLocation.x > 400)
    {   
        float dX = touchLocation.x - gun->getPosition().x;
        float dY = touchLocation.y - gun->getPosition().y;

        float angle = atan2(dY, dX);  
        gun->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle));

        cursor->setPosition(touchLocation);

        screenHeld = false; //not technically true but touchMoved bullet firing works differently (not scheduled, every movement instead)

        if (getTimeTick() - lastBulletFire > 50) //getTickTime is simple get system time method, works fine
        {
            fireBullet(angle);
        }
    }
}

//this is for touchBegan and has issues, scheduled to run every 50ms touch-held
void HelloWorld::fireBullets(CCTime dt) 
{
  if (screenHeld)
  {
    CCSprite* bullet = CCSprite::create("bullet.png");
    bullet->setPosition(ccp(gun->getPosition().x, gun->getPosition().y));
    bullet->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(touchAngle));

    //send bullet towards touchlocation
    bullet->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCMoveBy::create(1.5f, ccp(800 * cos(touchAngle), 800 * sin(touchAngle))), NULL));

    this->addChild(bullet, 5);
  }
}


//this is for touchMoved and works fine, everytime finger is moved bullet fired
void HelloWorld::fireBullet(float angle) 
{
  CCSprite* bullet = CCSprite::create("bullet.png");
  bullet->setPosition(ccp(gun->getPosition().x, gun->getPosition().y)); //add a random spread to the y value (or maybe the y-value of the destination)
  this->addChild(bullet, 5);

  bullet->setRotation(-CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle));

  bullet->runAction(CCSequence::create(CCMoveBy::create(1.5f, ccp(800 * cos(angle), 800 * sin(angle))), NULL));

  lastBulletFire = getTimeTick();
}
```

Comment: Because cocos2d-x is multiplatform and im developing on android phone

Comment: Where is getTimeTick() defined?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, it wasn't anything to do with actions/schedulers but the fact that I wasn't calling retain() on the bullets. Normally I'd manage C++ memory manually but this hybrid style threw my off